# How to determine the type of constructor based on the passed class?

Tags: typescript

```
const createObject = (ClassName: any, constructorProps: any) => {
  return new ClassName(constructorProps)
}

interface IProps {
  text: string;
}

class Class {
  constructor({text}: IProps) {
    console.log(text);
  }
}

const obj = createObject(Class, {name: ''}) //no error
```

In this case, I can pass any object in the second parameter to createObject. How to make the second parameter based on the class constructor type? It is advisable that the createObject call remains as in the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `any` is essentially asking the compiler never to give you an error; any value is assignable to the `any` type, and the `any` type is assignable to any other type, so you can write `createObject("hello", "goodbye");` and get no error from the compiler.

In order to start enforcing some type safety, you want the `ClassName` argument to have a constructor call signature; that is, it should be "[newable](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/callable#newable)" with one argument.  Something like `ClassName: new (arg: any) => any`.

In order to represent the constraint that the `ClassName`'s argument is the same type as `constructorProps`, the `createObject()` function needs to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) in that type.  It also helps if you make it generic in the return type of the constructor so that the compiler understands what comes out of `createObject()`.

Here's how I'd write the typing:

```
const createObject = <A, T>(ClassName: new (arg: A) => T, constructorProps: A) => {
    return new ClassName(constructorProps);
}
```

Now you should get more reasonable behavior:

```
const obj = createObject(Class, { name: '' }) // error!
const betterObj = createObject(Class, { text: "" }); // okay
// const betterObj: Class
```

The compiler complains unless you pass in an `IProps`, and it knows that a `Class` instance comes out.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBMBOBTAhlRB5ARgK0cWAvDADwCCANDACoB8AFAMIA2yEEAcsgLaIBcMYRAHcYdZPADm-UgEoYBGtUqhIUeAFd8IeAAV4IAA4RpchTADeAWABQMOzCRR18MAOExmrDt0R0V0DS1dfSMZAG4bAF8bGwBLMDR4ADNkYEQYAEk9QwgLG3sYNAAPKH4A+IkI62jbG2AWNg8G3Ktbe381TShtOnNCxBKYSP4skIg5VoKC-xAmRAA6JhAJOmKocPz7Gpq68GgYEBx5OCRUDBw8KEZmyj6wH34AckehuQB6N5hEeH14AEJdqoYJhEFBElhsMcECg0BDLtcvLd+iV+AAiVGvMIwD4HADWyAAnjYcR1gaDwTh+J42EA)